# How long would it take for me to mine a bitcoin with a TItan XP nvidia

Tags: time

How long would it take me to mine 1 bitcoin with an nvidia titan xp graphics card?
ty for helping if u do.

Comment: Wait so if this isnt good what should I use to be able to result in the maximum efficient to get bitcoins. I am willing to spend around 2k-3k dollars.

Comment: See the link in my answer. It's a bitcoin mining hardware guide that gives you the price for each piece of hardware along with how much bit coin you can expect to mine. Keep in mind this is constantly changing.

Answer (score 4):

In short: don't.

The hardware comparison page on the (mostly outdated) Bitcoin wiki does not have information on the Titan XP card, but lists around 200 Mhash/s for the GTX 590. A GTX 590 has 1024 CUDA cores, while the Titan XP has 3840. Extrapolating using this, we can estimate the performance at around 750 Mhash/s.

At the current difficulty, that amount of hashrate will let you mine a block on average once per 135000 years. If you use pooled mining, you can get incremental payouts for shares (partial proof of work). You may earn 1 BTC around once per 10000 years, while paying around $2000000 in electricity costs during that time (at 10c/kWh).

So don't. GPU mining has been superseded by FPGA and ASIC mining since around 2013.

Comment: And this is even assuming that the rewards and difficulty remain constant. So the reality is even worse than this.

Answer (score 1):

A long time. It's not really feasible to mine bitcoins with gpus anymore as there are special purpose asic chips now used to mine.
According to this [link](https://hackernoon.com/oh-bitcoin-is-still-a-thing-should-i-start-mining-then-f5c015adc1f4)

- CPU mining eventually gave way to GPU mining (where 1 GPU = ~28 CPUs)¹
- GPU mining eventually gave way to FPGA/ASIC mining (1 ASIC first-gen = ~33 GPUs)¹
- ASIC mining rapidly improved until running headlong into Moore’s    Law (1 ASIC today = ~212 ASICs first-gen)

Here is a list of what's [currently used to mine bitcoin](https://www.bitcoinmining.com/bitcoin-mining-hardware/) (2017).